# ubuntu - wget - website address becomes part of directory structure

Tags: ubuntu, wget

I am trying to download some kaggle data.

i was orignall using wget -x --load-cookies cookies.txt https://www.kaggle.com/c/second-annual-data-science-bowl/download/train.zip in the ubuntu shell

the problem was that the files were downloaded in my AWS instance in a directory structure www.kaggle.com/c/second-annual-data-science-bowl/download/

i was trying to avoid this, and following tips on this website, i have included the -nh commmand. this causes the files to download in a directory structure second-annual-data-science-bowl/download/

is there a way to avoid any directory structure - and to instruct wget to drop the train.zip in e.g. a data folder? i have tried to add -P /data/ - but with no result.

I am sure this must be described somewhere - but so far i have not been successful in finding it. any help welcome

W

Comment: this question is not for SO

Answer (score 0):

Just leave the `-x` out. It forces the generation of directories. If left, it puts the file in the current working directory.